# In PySide2 how to reimplement QWidget::nativeEvent

Tags: python, qt, winapi, pyside2

As described in [PySide2 Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=qwidget), `PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget` doesn't has a virtual function `nativeEvent` which is available and reimplementable in Qt5 for C++. I have tried to reimplement it, but it is not called ever. A test example is following:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QSize
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400,300)
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print("enterEvent") # this log is printed when mouse enters
        return super().enterEvent(event)
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print("leaveEvent") # this log is printed when mouse leaves
        return super().leaveEvent(event)
    def nativeEvent(self, eventType, message, result):
        print("nativeEvent") # never see this log
        return super().nativeEvent(eventType, message, result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    widget = MainWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

While, in C++ I can observe a lot of calling of `nativeEvent`:

```
### MainWidget.h ###

#pragma once
#include <QWidget>
class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MainWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QWidget(parent) {}
  QSize sizeHint();
protected:
  bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result);
};

### MainWidget.cpp ###

#include "MainWidget.h"
QSize MainWidget::sizeHint()
{
  return QSize(400, 300);
}
bool MainWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
  printf("nativeEvent\n"); // this is printed many times at the beginning of the application
  return QWidget::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);
}

### main.cpp ###

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MainWidget.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  AllocConsole();
  freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
  printf("Start..");
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWidget w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Is there any way to reimplement the `nativeEvent` method in PySide2? Or to handle Windows messages?

Comment: The issue will be resolved in PySide2 5.12.0: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-790

Comment: So you have to wait, on the other hand your implementation of nativeEvent is incorrect since it receives 2 parameters and returns a list of 2 elements: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/76150/pyside790_win.py

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks a lot. But I'm a little confused. As the documentation has not listed out the declaration of `nativeEvent`, how can we know how many parameters are received and how many values should be returned? As for me, I followed the declaration in C++ documentation, which shows that the method takes three parameters and returns a bool value.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have tried PyQt5. Now I understand that it is possibly because that in Qt C++ the third parameter is the pointer of the results. While in Python we can return multiple values so we can set the result by return values.